# csv to kml file New Zealand

Tags: r, csv, gis, kml, google-earth

I am trying to generate a kml file from a csv file so it can be plotted in Google earth. I am using this code I found in another help section and it seems to work fine for the generation of a kml but the points that are plotted are wrong.

```
library("sp")
library("rgdal")
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- c("x", "y")
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
meuse_ll <- spTransform(meuse, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
writeOGR(meuse_ll["zinc"], "meuse.kml", layer="zinc", driver="KML")
```

First fix was to get rid of the decimal places, that took me from France to NZ but the points are still out by a wide margin. Instead of being North of Auckland New Zealand they are south of the Chatham Islands. I suspect that I am dealing with a projection miss match or fudge factor issue. I have also tried copying the zip file from here: http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/
To use NZGD49 in the hopes that that would work but it throws up this error:

```
meuse_ll2 <- spTransform(test, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NZGD49"))
#Error in spTransform(test, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NZGD49")) : 
#  error in evaluating the argument 'CRSobj' in selecting a method for function           'spTransform': Error in CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NZGD49") : 
#unknown elliptical parameter name
```

So any ideas how I can work out?

## Example data:

```
Date     Time    Latitude1   Longitude1
27/09/2013   12:18:02   -36.67593   174.429688
27/09/2013   12:18:03   -36.675892  174.42981
```

Comment: Are you saying that you're having problems with the first example that you posted?  As in the meuse dataset plots in NZ when you open GoogleEarth?  It works fine for me.  I would check that you're up to date on R ([1] rgdal_0.8-11 sp_1.0-13) and then check your GE preferences.

Comment: Using R studio, version.string R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26), all packages upto date. I am not certain what GE Preferences are.

Meuse is an inbuilt set (from Germany I think) and the code works fine, the problem is with my data. If I use it raw data straight off the GPS unit I am tracking pigeons in France instead of Auckland, New Zealand. The meuse data did not have any decimal places and was representing the lat long as one integer. So I removed them from my data set by multiplying it by 10000. After that I ended up on the correct side of the planet and hemisphere but still off by a 1400km

Comment: Can you get me access to some of your data?  I enjoy working with the spatial packages, so I can try to help you out.  Also, the packages will play better with R 3.0.2, as they are updated very frequently (sp in particular).

Comment: Sure e-mail me j.guilbert@auckland.ac.nz

Cheers!